# Check Microsoft Office 2007 Editions

Tags: microsoft-office

MS Office comes [in a few editions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_2007), professional, standard etc.

How to check what editions I have?

Comment: What year is it from and what office programs do you have?

Comment: 2007, MS Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control Panel -> Add or remove software (Uninstall program in Windows7), find Microsoft Office in the list and check out the edition.

Comment: This can show multiple installed versions if you have upgraded.  I currently see both 2007 and 2003.

Comment: But the author has Office 2007, he wants to know the edition.

Comment: Good point!  +1, this is the better way to go.  Removed my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry to report that the Uninstall Program Menu doesn't show the Office 2007 edition also

Comment: I have no more ideas, may be you had a custom MS Office installer, or Public Beta...